# Getting Started with Tornado

Tags: python, twisted, tornado

After installing the necessary packages through apt (python 2.5, simplejson etc) I get an error when I try to run the demos.

```
: Request instance has no attribute 'responseHeaders'
/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/tornado/web.py, line 404 in flush
402    for k,v in self._generate_headers():
403      if isinstance(v, list):
404        self.request.responseHeaders.setRawHeaders(k, v)
405      else:
Self
request 
twisted.web.server.Request instance @ 0x85da24c 
Locals
self    
k   'Set-Cookie'
v   
List instance @ 0x85da46c
```

Here is proof that the necessary packages are installed

```
/web/tmp/tornado/demos/helloworld# dpkg -l | grep python2.5
ii  python2.5                             2.5.2-2ubuntu6                                             An interactive high-level object-oriented la
ii  python2.5-dev                         2.5.2-2ubuntu6                                             Header files and a static library for Python
ii  python2.5-minimal                     2.5.2-2ubuntu6                                             A minimal subset of the Python language 
# dpkg -l | grep simplejson
ii  python-simplejson                     1.7.3-1  
# dpkg -l | grep pycurl
ii  python-pycurl                         7.16.4-1
```

Seems that not too many people have been trying out this Tornado thing from friendfeed. Anyone have any suggestions/hints to help me get up and running with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was  under the impression tornado didn't depend on twisted. Have you tried the "official" version? line 404 is completely different.

http://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/web.py

```
def flush(self, include_footers=False):
    """Flushes the current output buffer to the nextwork."""
    if self.application._wsgi:
        raise Exception("WSGI applications do not support flush()") #line 404
    if not self._headers_written:
        self._headers_written = True
        headers = self._generate_headers()
    else:
        headers = ""
```

Other than that, I'd try installing twisted and see what happens

Comment: Tornado does not depend on Twisted.

Comment: that's kind of what I meant guy when I said "I was under the impression tornado didn't depend on twisted."